# How to make my logistic model more flexible?

Tags: r, regression, self-study, logistic

I'm working on a homework assignment, and I'm not sure if I did it right up until this point, and I'm not sure exactly where to go from here. [image: This is my homework question]

[Here is the circle.txt file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/owr58km96bj4tzj/circle.txt?dl=0)

I understand the first question well enough. I just did some basic visual interpretation with this code

```
colnames(circle)[1] = "X"
colnames(circle)[2] = "Y"
attach(circle)
plot(X,Y,
     xlim = c(-1,1),
     ylim = c(-1,1)
     )
Xgiven0 = circle[circle$V3 == 0, 1]
Xgiven1 = circle[circle$V3 == 1, 1]
Ygiven0 = circle[circle$V3 == 0, 2]
Ygiven1 = circle[circle$V3 == 1, 2]

plot(Xgiven0,Ygiven0,
     xlim = c(-1,1),
     ylim = c(-1,1)
     )
# plot(Xgiven0,Ygiven1)
# plot(Xgiven1,Ygiven0)
plot(Xgiven1,Ygiven1,
     xlim = c(-1,1),
     ylim = c(-1,1)
     )
```

For part b), I wrote this

```
glm_fit = glm(V3 ~., data = circle, family = binomial)
glm_pred = predict(glm_fit, type="response")
glm_pred = glm_pred > .5
table(true = V3, pred = glm_pred)
summary(glm_fit)$coefficients
```

It appears that a simple logistic model is not sufficient because the confusion matrix does not do a good job predicting anything, and we have poor confidence for all of the coefficients. I don't know if I fit the model correctly up until this point.

Furthermore, I don't know how to approach part c). How do I make the logistic model more flexible? (the professor's instructions are that we stay within the bounds of a logistic model and do not use something else like QDA)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is homework, this is guidance and not a complete answer.

If you color code the pass/fails on your first plot:

```
plot(X,Y,
     xlim = c(-1,1),
     ylim = c(-1,1), col=ifelse(circle$V3, "blue", "red"),  pch=19
)
```

[image]

From the figure, the passing points are towards the center and the failing points are towards the fringes.  Therefore it is unlikely a simple linear fit for x and y from -1 to 1 will very successful(this is your original model).  Try transforming your initial data; absolute value, squaring, etc..., maybe add adding an x&y interaction term.  Do any of these actions improve the model?

I used the absolute value of x and y and saw an improvement. There is room improvement.

Here is the starting data:

```
structure(list(X = c(0.051267, -0.092742, -0.21371, -0.375, -0.51325, 
-0.52477, -0.39804, -0.30588, 0.016705, 0.13191, 0.38537, 0.52938, 
0.63882, 0.73675, 0.54666, 0.322, 0.16647, -0.046659, -0.17339, 
-0.47869, -0.60541, -0.62846, -0.59389, -0.42108, -0.11578, 0.20104, 
0.46601, 0.67339, -0.13882, -0.29435, -0.26555, -0.16187, -0.17339, 
-0.28283, -0.36348, -0.30012, -0.23675, -0.06394, 0.062788, 0.22984, 
0.2932, 0.48329, 0.64459, 0.46025, 0.6273, 0.57546, 0.72523, 
0.22408, 0.44297, 0.322, 0.13767, -0.0063364, -0.092742, -0.20795, 
-0.20795, -0.43836, -0.21947, -0.13882, 0.18376, 0.22408, 0.29896, 
0.50634, 0.61578, 0.60426, 0.76555, 0.92684, 0.82316, 0.96141, 
0.93836, 0.86348, 0.89804, 0.85196, 0.82892, 0.79435, 0.59274, 
0.51786, 0.46601, 0.35081, 0.28744, 0.085829, 0.14919, -0.13306, 
-0.40956, -0.39228, -0.74366, -0.69758, -0.75518, -0.69758, -0.4038, 
-0.38076, -0.50749, -0.54781, 0.10311, 0.057028, -0.10426, -0.081221, 
0.28744, 0.39689, 0.63882, 0.82316, 0.67339, 1.0709, -0.046659, 
-0.23675, -0.15035, -0.49021, -0.46717, -0.28859, -0.61118, -0.66302, 
-0.59965, -0.72638, -0.83007, -0.72062, -0.59389, -0.48445, -0.0063364, 
0.63265), Y = c(0.69956, 0.68494, 0.69225, 0.50219, 0.46564, 
0.2098, 0.034357, -0.19225, -0.40424, -0.51389, -0.56506, -0.5212, 
-0.24342, -0.18494, 0.48757, 0.5826, 0.53874, 0.81652, 0.69956, 
0.63377, 0.59722, 0.33406, 0.005117, -0.27266, -0.39693, -0.60161, 
-0.53582, -0.53582, 0.54605, 0.77997, 0.96272, 0.8019, 0.64839, 
0.47295, 0.31213, 0.027047, -0.21418, -0.18494, -0.16301, -0.41155, 
-0.2288, -0.18494, -0.14108, 0.012427, 0.15863, 0.26827, 0.44371, 
0.52412, 0.67032, 0.69225, 0.57529, 0.39985, 0.55336, 0.35599, 
0.17325, 0.21711, -0.016813, -0.27266, 0.93348, 0.77997, 0.61915, 
0.75804, 0.7288, 0.59722, 0.50219, 0.3633, 0.27558, 0.085526, 
0.012427, -0.082602, -0.20687, -0.36769, -0.5212, -0.55775, -0.7405, 
-0.5943, -0.41886, -0.57968, -0.76974, -0.75512, -0.57968, -0.4481, 
-0.41155, -0.25804, -0.25804, 0.041667, 0.2902, 0.68494, 0.70687, 
0.91886, 0.90424, 0.70687, 0.77997, 0.91886, 0.99196, 1.1089, 
1.087, 0.82383, 0.88962, 0.66301, 0.64108, 0.10015, -0.57968, 
-0.63816, -0.36769, -0.3019, -0.13377, -0.060673, -0.067982, 
-0.21418, -0.41886, -0.082602, 0.31213, 0.53874, 0.49488, 0.99927, 
0.99927, -0.030612), V3 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -118L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```